# Diffraction from the Earths edge

Tags: visible-light, photons, interference, diffraction

I recorded an eight hour time lapse video of the afternoon as the sun set. I was surprised to see at about the halfway point of the video the light begin to cycle through lighter and darker phases with the pattern getting closer and closer or (faster and faster). This reassembles the fringe pattern of a single edge which I have written about at billalsept.com "Single Edge Certainty" I searched for information on viewing an occultation affect like this but nothing so far. Has this ever been recorded before? I new that occultation could be observed from distant objects like the moon passing in front of stars and planets but didn't realize we could see this phenomena standing right in the middle of the Earths own shadow.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/54j7bh9rqy3l2ha/Sunset%20Edge%20Diffraction.mov?dl=0

Comment: You are likely seeing clouds (or haze as the sun sets) varying over a few minutes (wave patterns in clouds are really common due to atmospheric waves).  What it isn't is diffraction of light.

Comment: @tfb there wasn't a cloud in the sky all day. Single edge diffraction is a real and documented phenomena. If you watch the video you will see that the pattern is a perfect diminishing sequence that matches the single edge diffraction pattern. I am sure we are seeing this reflect off the atmosphere as the sun sets. Maybe I'm the first to ever record this.

Comment: I think you should do some elementary calculations involving the wavelength of sunlight, the rate the sun moves across the sky and the timescale of the phenomenon you saw (always assuming it was not an artifact of the camera: without detailed exposure/aperture/sensor iso information about each frame this is not possible to rule out).  You will then realise why this can not be diffraction

Comment: @tfb do you know what a single edge diffraction pattern looks like? How can you be sure that particular phenomenon is not happening? After all it happens on every other edge in the universe where light shines. Why would earth to be the only edge to not diffract light?

Comment: I don't see anything in the video. I see lots of color banding due to the camera quality, but I don't see anything that looks like diffraction.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy thanks for looking. Start looking at the 15 second mark or about halfway through. You will see the sky suddenly get brighter then darker, then brighter and darker again and again each time getting faster and faster. This would be the effect you would see if you were to skim over the image of a single edge diffraction pattern. Google search single edged defraction pattern and see the image. As the earth turns we are moving through the diffraction pattern as the fringes get closer and closer which appears to flash faster and faster.

Comment: What's wrong with this question? Bill has posted experimental results and some reasoning as what he thinks it might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply speculation together with a proposed experiment to test the speculation.

I believe what you are seeing is your camera autogaining as the light fades. The light's probably fading at a rate that the controller is not really designed to cope with and poor design has left the control loop with a tendency to hunt when presented with such a rate. You could try the experiment again with:

1. A different camera;
2. More precisely, you could use a camera with a very high sensitivity chip and use the software controls to hold the *f*-number and exposure time steady. That is, you don't give the autogain control a chance to taint the results, and you can impart your own smooth gain versus time profile to the sequence afterwards for clearer viewing.

If my theory is right, 2. in particular should get rid of the effect.

Comment: you may be right. I was just doing that exact thing. I started a different camera about an hour ago and Now I will wait for the results.  It was just interesting the way the pattern became faster and faster. Thank you

Comment: @BillAlsept To get meaningful results it's not sufficient to use another camera: you must also either hold aperture, exposure *and any compensation applied to the sensor* ('iso setting') constant, or you must record all those numbers in each frame, from which you can calculate the actual brightness of parts of the image.  Very often this information is stored in the EXIF data.  It is probably preferable to force all the settings constant.